# glPolygonMode(GL_BACK,GL_LINE) isn't working

Tags: opengl

```
glEnable(GL_CULL_FACE);
glCullFace(GL_FRONT);

glPolygonMode(GL_BACK,GL_LINE);
```

In the above code sample, glPolygonMode throws invalid enum error? How to resolve this issue?

Comment: `GL_BACK` isn't available in the core profile, assuming that's what you're using.

Comment: even glPolygonMode(GL_FRONT,GL_LINE); is failing in  glEnable(GL_CULL_FACE);

 glPolygonMode(GL_FRONT,GL_LINE);

Comment: `GL_FRONT` isn't available in core profile either. Only `GL_FRONT_AND_BACK` is available.

Comment: Neither `GL_BACK` or `GL_FRONT` are available for `glPolygonMode` in the core profile - only `GL_FRONT_AND_BACK`.

Comment: Thanks. I am planning to draw ink outlines for a model by culling front face and drawing back faces in wire frame with line width 2.5 and then drawing front face in gL_FILL mode. But it seems likes even glLineWidth is not working in core profile. Wat is the alternative?

Answer (score 9):

`GL_INVALID_ENUM`is generated if either face or mode (respectively the first and second parameter) of your question is not an accepted value. Your first parameter must be `GL_FRONT_AND_BACK` for front- and back-facing polygons as `GL_FRONT` and `GL_BACK` has been deprecated for this method.

**EDIT**

Since you seems to be asking an other question in your comment. If you want to draw an ink around a filled polygon you should render your geometry two times;  render once filled and once wireframe. Slightly shift the wireframe to avoid depth fighting. the two geometries might overlap otherwise

```
// first draw your polygon filled (this is assuming your glPolygonMode is set to GL_FILL - this is the default mode normally)
// draw your polygons

// offset the wireframe 
glEnable(GL_POLYGON_OFFSET_LINE);
glPolygonOffset(-1,-1);

// draw the wireframe
glPolygonMode(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_LINE);
// draw the same polygons again

// restore default polygon mode
glPolygonMode(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_FILL);

glDisable(GL_POLYGON_OFFSET_LINE);
```

Comment: Thanks, the tip to always use `GL_FRONT_AND_BACK` made my program work.